# Bug na apresentação do código no preview de edição

Tags: bug, status-intencional

Nesta pergunta [Nome da variável passada no argumento da função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56770/nome-da-vari%C3%A1vel-passada-no-argumento-da-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o) ao editar, o *preview* do código aparece desta forma:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Mas depois da edição feita já aparece direito:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Isto é bug?

Comment: O `<sub>` e o `<sup>` também aparecem bem diferentes no _preview_, acho que isso é uma _feature_. Por isso temos nosso [chiqueirinho](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/317/3117).

Comment: @Math Não percebi o que têm a ver uma coisa com a outra.

Comment: Quis dizer que o _preview_ não é dos mais confiáveis.

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser considerado um bug do *preview*, porém a causa real do problema é que o código usado na pergunta utiliza tabs em vez de espaços, e o site não se dá muito bem com isso. Veja só:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]